# How do I find the most frequent number from patient_id

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

An image of the table to retrieve the data from:

[image]

REM  ADMISSION TABLE

INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (205,101,'2/2/2011','HB',114,'P','21/2/2011');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "most frequent number"? Patient who has most admissions? If so, then

```
select patient_id
from (select patient_id,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
      from admission
      group by patient_id
     )
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Appreciate the help again!

Answer (score 1):

```
select patient_id ,count(*) as patient_count
  from admission group by patient_id 
order by patient_count desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you want only patient_id then:

```
WITH temp as 
(
select patient_id ,count(*) as patient_count
      from admission group by patient_id 
    order by patient_count desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
select patient_id from temp;
```

Comment: @jOHNJACOBJINGLE First you accepted this answer and now you again rejected it. Atleast upvote for the answer

Comment: Sorry about that I am quite new to stack overflow I thought I could accept multiple answers at once. I was unable to upvote because They didn't allow me to do it till i reached a certain ranking. It says I need a 15 reputation. Appreciate your help!

Comment: No issues. You can upvote my answer. You need to click on up arrow present on left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

count group by patient_id and use [FETCH FIRST](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1#top-n) 1 ROWS ONLY:

```
select count(*) cnt, patient_id 
  from admission group by patient_id 
order by cnt desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you have Oracle < 12C R1, use rownum with subquery:

```
select *
from  
(select count(*) cnt, patient_id 
      from admission group by patient_id 
    order by cnt desc ) 
where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both case you case you can remove count(*) AS patient_max from the select if you just want patient_id

Oracle

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT patient_id,count(*) AS patient_max
           FROM admission 
           GROUP BY patient_id 
           ORDER BY count(*) DESC
 ) 
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Postgresq

```
 SELECT patient_id,count(*) AS patient_max
           FROM admission 
           GROUP BY patient_id 
           ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
           LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That won't work in Oracle, there's no LIMIT there.

Comment: Right I'm used to posrgesql, I corrected my answer